# ReactJS - How to redirect another page using history.push by passing data?

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, routes, react-hooks

In react app, I am using below packages

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-redux": "^7.1.3",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1"
```

Also using reducer like

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if(action.type === 'GET_FRIENDS'){
    return {...state};
  } else if (action.type === 'ADD_FRIEND'){
    return {state, friends: state.friends.concat(action.friend) };
  } else if (action.type === 'DELETE_FRIEND'){
    return {...state, friends: state.friends.filter(item => item.id !== parseInt(action.friendId))};
  }
  return state;
}
```

In main index.js,

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import List from './List';
import FormInput from './FormInput';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {reducer, initialState } from './reducer';

function Friends(){
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

   function handleDelete(id){
     dispatch({type: 'DELETE_FRIEND', friendId: id});
   }

   return(
     <Router>
       <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
         <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/list">List</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/create">Add</Link></li>
         </ul>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/"><Home /></Route>
           <Route path="/list"><List friends={state.friends} handleDelete={(id) => handleDelete(id)} /></Route>
           <Route path="/create"><FormInput /></Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
 }
 export default Friends;
```

And child component `FormInput` is like,

```
import React, { useReducer, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import {reducer, initialState } from '../reducer';

function FormInput(){
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const initFriend = {id: null, name: '', phone: '', email: '', work: '', city: ''};
  const [friend, setFriend] = useState(initFriend);
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleOnChange(e){
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFriend({...friend, [name]: value});
  }

  function handleOnSubmit(e){
    friend.id = (state.friends.length - 1) + 1;
    dispatch({type: 'ADD_FRIEND', friend: friend});
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push("/list");
  }

  return(
     <form onSubmit={(e) => handleOnSubmit(e)} autoComplete="off">
        <div className="form-group row">
           <label className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
           <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control form-control-lg" defaultValue={''} onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)} />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group row">
           <label className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone</label>
           <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="phone" className="form-control form-control-lg" defaultValue={''} onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)} />
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
    </form>
  );
}
export default FormInput;
```

Right now after form submission page is redirecting without updated data.

Actually I want to add a new `friend` data to `state.friends` after form submission. And also it should redirect to `/list` page by displaying newly added row.

Also please let me know the answer in detail because I am new to ReactJS.

Comment: The state from FormInput is only accessible to itself or its children unless you pass it down. Once you successfully submit the form and added data to the state, the state will be deleted because you're redirecting to another route and the FormInput component gets unmounted. If you want your state to be available across the app, you should create a state provider using React Context.

Comment: Actually I was added all state to parent component itself, at that point routing was not happened, so I changed like this way.

Comment: If you have lifted the state in parent component then just use some condition to check if the specific data is set or not under mounting of that component and get that data

Comment: Can you plz explain in detail..

Comment: @Shruthi You're using the same reducer from different component using useReducer, thus, the state returned from that reducer can only be accessed on that component. The changes you make to the state in FormInput gets deleted whenever you change route.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have lifted the state to parent component then will get updated list from reducer. But its not redirect to list page with new data, it stays in form page itself. How can I redirect in this case?

Comment: If you set the state in ```Friends``` component, then you must pass the ```dispatch``` as prop in ```FormInput``` like so:  ```<Route path="/create"><FormInput dispatch={dispatch} /></Route>```then delete the useReducer in ```FormInput```. It's not recommended to do this and it's much better to wrap your main component in a ```Provider```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same reducer which you used both in `Friends` component and `FormInput` component.

Whenever you submit the form and added data to the state in `FormInput`, the data you've just added will only be saved in `FormInput` and not in `Friends` component and the state will be deleted because the `FormInput` will be unmounted upon changing `route`.

To solve this, you need to use the `reducer` only in the parent/main which happened to be `Friends` component in your case and delete the `useReducer` hook in `FormInput`.

App.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import List from './List';
import FormInput from './FormInput';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {reducer, initialState } from './reducer';

function Friends(){
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

   function handleDelete(id){
     dispatch({type: 'DELETE_FRIEND', friendId: id});
   }

   return(
     <Router>
       <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
         <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/list">List</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/create">Add</Link></li>
         </ul>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/"><Home /></Route>
           <Route path="/list"><List friends={state.friends} handleDelete={(id) => handleDelete(id)} /></Route>
           <Route path="/create">
               <FormInput state={state} dispatch={dispatch}/> //PASS THE STATE & DISPATCH 
           </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
 }
 export default Friends;
```

Now you only need to use the passed dispatch and state prop in `FormInput`

```
function FormInput({ state, dispatch }){
  const initFriend = {id: null, name: '', phone: '', email: '', work: '', city: ''};
  const [friend, setFriend] = useState(initFriend);
  let history = useHistory();
 
  // ...
}
```

This though is not a good practice. That's why use `Context` in this case.
See the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-varahamihira-pb02t) demo for the context version.

For details about [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass state using history also.

````
    props.history.push({
    path:"/list",
    state:someData
})

In the list component
props.location.state ```
````

Comment: If the component is class component, it is ```this.props``` and if the component is a functional one, you need to pass props as argument.

Comment: Already tried, both will not support.. is there any package installation requires?